# An alternative to high-cost NPK sensors

Tags: sensors, agriculture

I want to design an IoT based fertilizer recommendation system in which using temperature, moisture, humidity and NPK sensors, you can obtain the data on soil nutrients and you will get the exact fertilizer name and amount to add for maximizing the yield and simultaneously reducing soil pollution. The NPK sensors currently available in the market are expensive and not feasible for small farmers. I'm completely new to IoT. I considered one possibility where one could  develop algorithms or models that estimate nutrient levels based on the available low-cost sensors (temperature, moisture, humidity). Is this a true possibility? If yes, then will it be accurate enough?

Comment: the temperature, moisture and humidity of a large pile of fertilizer can easily be the same as unfertilized soil ... your question is not about IoT

Comment: While I don’t think this is appropriate here, what is your notion of “expensive”? The sensor itself (without the wireless part) can be had for less than 20 euros apiece, probably a lot less in volume, and that’s just in less than 2 minutes of browsing…